# The letsencrypt error cannot be resolved and the cause is unknown

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I want to issue an SSL / TLS certificate with Let's encrypt.
I changed Nginx settings, installed certbot and tried to run it.
However, the cause of the error is not known and cannot be resolved.

I use Ubuntu, Nginx, Gunicorn.
The server is DigitalOcean.

This is what I think is the cause.
Please tell me if there are other causes.

This is the command I executed.

```
sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/letsencypt/ -d letyu.com
```

/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('certbot==0.23.0', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1266, in main
    return config.func(config, plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1157, in certonly
    lineage = _get_and_save_cert(le_client, config, domains, certname, lineage)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 118, in _get_and_save_cert
    lineage = le_client.obtain_and_enroll_certificate(domains, certname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/client.py", line 350, in obtain_and_enroll_certificate
    cert, chain, key, _ = self.obtain_certificate(domains)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/client.py", line 294, in obtain_certificate
    orderr = self._get_order_and_authorizations(csr.data, self.config.allow_subset_of_names)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/client.py", line 330, in _get_order_and_authorizations
    authzr = self.auth_handler.handle_authorizations(orderr, best_effort)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 80, in handle_authorizations
    self._respond(aauthzrs, resp, best_effort)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 153, in _respond
    self._poll_challenges(aauthzrs, chall_update, best_effort)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 224, in _poll_challenges
    raise errors.FailedChallenges(all_failed_achalls)
certbot.errors.FailedChallenges: Failed authorization procedure. letyu.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://letyu.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/_F6gkBb9_-OHATmw9JEUiAB6_xZGnZUghV7fgppnvEk []: "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>"
```

Comment: Your webserver is returning a 404 response for the file at `http://letyu.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/...`.

Comment: Please, show `nginx.conf` - it looks like Nginx returns 404 on requests from Let’s Encrypt